# Produce a comma separated list using StringBuilder

Tags: java

Following is my scenario, though I have achieved the desired output but I want it to be a decent and optimized code.

```
String arr[]={"we","er","rtt","yu","uu","ii"};

      StringBuilder strcat = new StringBuilder();

      for(int i1=0;i1<arr.length;i1++)
      {
          // Some processing
         strcat.append(arr[i1]);

         if(arr.length-1!=i1)
         {

              strcat.append(",");
         }
      }

     System.out.println("Value:"+strcat);
```

I have `String[]` array and some processing, after processing I want to append the values with comma(`,`).
the problem is  comma , it appends to last values also, that I don’t want, I have applied a logic. I don’t know whether it is correct.but output is correct.Please do correct me if I am wrong and do suggest if it has any other means to achieve.

Comment: Are you allowed to use third party library? what's your JDK version?

Comment: I need it in pure java.. without any other libraries

Comment: Guava's [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class is doing exactly this.

Comment: if it is in pure java code , it would be grateful

Comment: You can also try `Arrays.toString()` method packaged in core JDK... Though it will also add a `[]` surrounding the string...

Comment: @vineeth just keep on appending "," and at the end print strcat.substring(strcat.length()-1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nice trick I learned here

```
String SEPARATOR = "";
for(int i1=0;i1<arr.length;i1++)
{
    // Some processing
    strcat.append(SEPARATOR);
    strcat.append(arr[i1]);
    SEPARATOR = ",";
}
```

Comment: That is damn clever. :)

Comment: it will also add comma at the end of last value.

Comment: @androidXP not really, cause you add first `SEPARATOR`, so last iteration will make `,` + `arr[arr.lenght]` and finish, that's the "trick", `SEPARATOR` is empty first iteration, so no comma added at the begining and then you assign for the next ones, but first the `SEPARATOR` and later the content

Answer (score 19):

If you're using Java 8, there's already support for this in the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) class

```
String result = String.join(",", arr);
```

will result in

```
"we,er,rtt,yu,uu,ii"
```

Comment: @vineeth It's time to move to Java 8 :)

Comment: we have production and inhouse clients using java 7..so we cannot migrate very fastly to java 8

Comment: @vineeth you can't complain, I have `Java 5` apps still running :@#!·$****

Answer (score 1):

Java 8's streaming APIs allow a much neater solution:

```
String result = Arrays.asList(arr).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: As he is using Java 7, this would not work. And it does not consider the step where array element needs to be processed. However this would be my favorite solution.

Comment: This seems to be an overkill for a simple problem... `String.join()` seems much easier if we are going to use Java8 anyway...

Comment: You can replace `Arrays.asList(arr).stream()` with `Arrays.stream(arr)` to get a `Stream<T>`.

Comment: This is useful when you have a non-string list than you can map the stream and join it at the end: `myObjects.map(MyObject::getStringField).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it this way:

```
 strcat.append(arr[0]);
 for (int iCnt = 1;iCnt <arr.length;++iCnt) {
     strcat.append(",").append(arr[iCnt]);
 }
```

Comment: This would require additional code to handle empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches I usually see are:

- append comma after every element, then delete the last character before using the result
- prepend a comma to all elements except first (the check is easier this way, you can simply check `strcat.length() == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could append the 0th array element first (after ensuring that the array size is at least 1) and then append the commas *before* each element from 1 to length - 1.

Or you could do it the way you're doing it, and then remove the last comma by shortening the buffer with `StringBuilder.setLength(int)`.