# To remove commas the end of list of numbers

Tags: java

The question is to print out the elements having even actual position of even index starting from 1 and their sum in the following format.For example,
if number of elements is 6 and the elements are 
10, 20, 30, 40, 100 and 200, the output is obtained as

```
20, 40, 200
260
```

where the second line of output represents the sum of the even indexes but I got the output as

```
20, 40, 200
260
```

How can I get rid of the comma at the end?

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n, i, sum = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = input.nextInt();
        int[] data = new int[n];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            data[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(data[i] + ",");
                sum += data[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework...

Comment: `How can I get rid of the comma at the end?` - Don't print it. I'm being serious here: detect whether you reached the end or not and print the comma only when not.

Comment: simply run your loop n-1 and take the last input outside and don't display comma this time or you can put a check

Comment: make the comma string a variable (e.g. `String separator;` and chage to `(separator+data[i])`, before the loop insert `separator="";`, after the output statement insert `separator=",";` the useless assingment for all but the firs iteration is less of a performance problem than the `if` to check beeing the last/first loop.

Comment: Why are do you have a loop within the other loop, both using i as their index? Makes it very hard to read the code.

Comment: @RocAràjol The code doesn't have nested loops. The OP just like to throw the curly braces in random locations. There are two loops one after the other that both use `i` as the loop index variable.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt https://twitter.com/UdellGames/status/788690145822306304?s=08

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this cases I use a simple trick:

```
String SEPARATOR = "";
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    data[i] = input.nextInt();
}
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(SEPARATOR + data[i]);
        sum += data[i];
        SEPARATOR = ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: Good pragmatic solution. SEPARATOR should be lower case (since it's not a constant).

Comment: @adriaan technically it's not a constant but is used in same way, that's why I [use it always in `UPPERCASE` to clarify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987478/produce-a-comma-separated-list-using-stringbuilder/32987571#32987571)

Comment: It is not used 'in the same way' since you are reassigning the variable. Sonar will flag this as an unconventional variable name (and probably your IDE too)

Comment: @adrian You're right... But you reassign it only once and to a fixed value, I understand your point and conventions but in my team this kind of variables are `UPPERCASE`

Comment: Well, your team can do what they like of course. But it's not following Java conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ternary operator to do it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(data[i] + i != n-1 ? "," : "");
        sum += data[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
// create Scanner in try-with-resources block so it gets closed at the end
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    int size = input.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
        // read and discard even index (odd position)
        input.nextInt();
        int value = input.nextInt();
        sb.append(value).append(",");
        sum += value;
    }

    // remove last separator
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

    // if the size is odd, read and discard one more number
    if (size % 2 == 1) {
        input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.printf("%s%n%s", sb, sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java 8 solution using streams:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Adder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StringJoiner numbers = new StringJoiner(",");
        final boolean[] flipFlop = new boolean[]{true};
        int size = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int sum = in.lines()
                .limit(size)
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .filter(i -> {
                    flipFlop[0] = !flipFlop[0];
                    return flipFlop[0];
                })
                .peek(i -> numbers.add(String.valueOf(i)))
                .sum();
        System.out.println(numbers);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```